# Interating through an Array in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

I am a beginner in Swift and am using Swift 3.0.
I have following setup:

```
var profileArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()

profileArray.append(["profile_name":profileName.text! as AnyObject,"wifi":wifiValue.isOn as AnyObject,"bluetooth":btoothValue.isOn as AnyObject,"airplane":airplaneValue.isOn as AnyObject,"mobile_data":mdataValue.isOn as AnyObject,"not_disturb":nodisturbValue.isOn as AnyObject,"loc_service":locationValue.isOn as AnyObject,"ring_vol":ringVolume as AnyObject,"operation":editOperation as AnyObject])

//Value stored in this array
Array:

[
    [
        "wifi": 1,
        "bluetooth": 1,
        "not_disturb": 1,
        "operation": 1,
        "airplane": 1,
        "profile_name": loud,
        "loc_service": 1,
        "ring_vol": 4,
        "mobile_data": 1
    ],
    [
        "wifi": 1,
        "bluetooth": 0,
        "not_disturb": 1,
        "operation": 0,
        "airplane": 1,
        "profile_name": quite,
        "loc_service": 0,
        "ring_vol": 1,
        "mobile_data": 1
    ] 
]
```

My question is how do I iterate through this array and check the value of "operation" index?

Answer (score 1):

Call a `flatMap` operation on the array of dictionaries, attempting to access key `"operation"` in each dict:

```
let correspondingOperationValues = profileArray.flatMap { $0["operation"] }
print(correspondingOperationValues) // [1, 0]
```

Also, consider if you really want to use dictionaries of `AnyObject` values: `Any` *could* be more appropriate, but also a wrapper such as `Any` code be a code-smells marker.

If the keys of your dictionaries are "static" (known at compile time), you might consider constructing a custom type to use rather than a dictionary, e.g.:

```
struct CustomSettings {
    let wifi: Bool
    let bluetooth: Bool
    let not_disturb: Bool
    let operation: Bool
    let airplane: Bool
    let profile_name: String
    let loc_service: Bool
    let ring_vol: Int
    let mobile_data: Bool
}

let profileArray = [
    CustomSettings(
        wifi: true,
        bluetooth: true,
        not_disturb: true,
        operation: true,
        airplane: true,
        profile_name: "foo",
        loc_service: true,
        ring_vol: 4,
        mobile_data: true),
    CustomSettings(
        wifi: true,
        bluetooth: false,
        not_disturb: true,
        operation: false,
        airplane: true,
        profile_name: "foo",
        loc_service: false,
        ring_vol: 1,
        mobile_data: true)
]

let correspondingOperationValues = profileArray
    .map { $0.operation } // [true, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
for dict in profileArray {

    if let value = dict["operation"] {
        print(value)   // or do something else with the value
    }
}
```

A Swift Dictionary returns an `Optional` value (`nil` if the key wasn't present) so you can use optional binding to check for the value.